List of Android SDK command-line tools releases, version by version
I want to get URLs to download any version of Android Command-Line tools. Is there such a list?
What I know:

sdkmanager --list --verbose doesn't print URLs

https://dl.google.com/android/repository returns 404

https://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases.html only contains extremely old releases

cat $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/source.properties prints
Pkg.Revision=11.0
Pkg.Path=cmdline-tools;11.0
Pkg.Desc=Android SDK Command-line Tools

Not very useful.



A comment under this answer has the actual answer - that is, this GitHub gist.
Basically, the repository contents list is available (in XML) at https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml.
You can use the linked Go program in the gist, or curl it and use e.g. yq to convert from XML to JSON, and from there on, we can use jq to perform more granular selection of packages, for example:
curl -s https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml \
  | yq -p xml -o json \
  | jq '."sdk-repository" | .remotePackage[] | select(."display-name" | startswith("Android SDK Command-line Tools"))'

If you want simpler output, then try this:
ANDROID_SDK_URL=https://dl.google.com/android/repository

curl -s "$ANDROID_SDK_URL/repository2-1.xml" \
  | yq -p xml -o json \
  | jq '."sdk-repository" | .remotePackage[] | select(."display-name" | startswith("Android SDK Command-line Tools"))' \
  | jq --arg ANDROID_SDK_URL "$ANDROID_SDK_URL" '{
      name: ."+@path",
      linux: ($ANDROID_SDK_URL + "/" + (.archives.archive[] | select(."host-os" == "linux") | .complete.url)),
      macos: ($ANDROID_SDK_URL + "/" + (.archives.archive[] | select(."host-os" == "macosx") | .complete.url)),
      windows: ($ANDROID_SDK_URL + "/" + (.archives.archive[] | select(."host-os" == "windows") | .complete.url))
    }'

